# Looking for a node.js sandbox like a framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, frameworks

I'm looking for a node.js sandbox with :

-User managment (Auth (like the module passport [here](https://npmjs.org/package/passport)), access control

-Form managment with controls like helpers

-Crud/scaffold generator (Add, Edit, Update, Delete etc...)

-Using MVC architecture, like a framework

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

I don't really think there will be such a framework does all the work for you prepackaged, but I think something that is very similar or close to what you want would be:

1. [Sails.js](http://sailsjs.org)
2. [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/)

Personally I would say SailsJS would be something you want.

I don't really want to list things that it's mentioned on their site but I'm sure you will find that is what you are going to be using.